# SELECT statement avoid duplicating in multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct-values

I have a table called `ItemTransaction` with columns `itemId, Qty, BatchNo` columns. I want to select the items which all are having `qty >=0` and `<= 100`, and `itemid` and `batchno` unique.

The problem now is a single item can be repeated in the different `batchno` with different `qty`.

```
select 
    ItemID, Quantity, BatchNo 
from  
    ItemTransaction 
where 
    Quantity >= 0 and Quantity <= 100 
group by 
    ItemID, Quantity, BatchNo
```

When I'm running the above query its giving duplicate values. Don't know how to fetch distinct values from the above mentioned condition.

Sample data

```
|ItemID | Quantity | BatchNo |
+----------------------------+
|1095   | 3        |   1     |
|1095   | 0        |   1     |
|1098   | 10       |   2     |
|1099   | 0        |   3     |
|1099   | 20       |   3     |
|1099   | 80       |   3     |
```

Expected output :

```
|ItemID | Quantity | BatchNo |
+----------------------------+
|1095   | 3        |   1     |
|1098   | 10       |   2     |
|1099   | 80       |   3     |
```

here quantity may be any which is greater in the batch or lesser in the batch.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the grouping. Can there be different quantities of the same item with the same batch number?

Comment: add sample data and desired Output

Comment: Add the expected output to avoid confusions make sure your sample data covers all your scenarious

Comment: Your input data is already distinct. Perhaps you want distinct ItemID-BatchNo ?

Comment: @toddlermenot yes, distinct Itemid and batch no

Comment: @user3028959 then NoDisplayName's answer would be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
SELECT ItemID,
       Max(Quantity)Quantity,
       BatchNo
FROM   ItemTransaction 
WHERE  Quantity >= 0
       AND Quantity <= 100
GROUP  BY ItemID,
          BatchNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `Distinct` keyword

```
select Distinct ItemID, Quantity, BatchNo 
from ItemTransaction 
where Quantity >= 0 and Quantity <= 100 
group by ItemID,Quantity,BatchNo
```

Answer (score 0):

add having clause after group by and distinct is correct too

```
 select ItemID,Quantity,BatchNo from ItemTransaction 
 where Quantity >= 0 and Quantity <= 100 
 group by ItemID,Quantity,BatchNo
 having count(ItemID)=1 ;
```

As when i posted my above answer your question was not complete; as of now it with expected output so the below query will give the correct answer .

```
  select ItemID,Quantity,BatchNo from Itm 
  where Quantity >= 0 and Quantity <= 100 and 
  (ItemID,Quantity) in 
  (select ItemID,max(Quantity) from itm group by ItemID) ;
```

Comment: it will give you only the items which is having count 1. i don't think so it will help me, i want all the items but distinct values.

Comment: By seeing your complete question and expected output you posted on edit ,so now your expected output query i posted it above